# Argument of type 'State' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have just started using typescript with React. I tried using it with React useReducer hook but I am stuck because of a weird error.

Here is my code:

```
    export interface ContractObj {
      company: string;
      negotiationRenewalDate: string;
      periodEnd: string;
      periodStart: string;
      scheduleForRenewal: boolean;
      contractId: string;
    }

    type State = {
      loading: boolean;
      error: boolean;
      contractsData: ContractObj[];
    };

    type Action =
      | { type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS'; payload: ContractObj[] }
      | { type: 'FETCH_ERROR'; payload: null };

    const initialState: State = {
      loading: true,
      error: false,
      contractsData: []
    };

    const reducer = (state: State, action: Action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
          return {
            loading: false,
            error: false,
            contractsData: action.payload
          };
        case 'FETCH_ERROR':
          return {
            loading: false,
            error: true
          };
        default: {
          return state;
        }
      }
    };
    export const Contracts: React.FC<Props> = () => {
      const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
```

It gives me an error when I hover over `initialState` i.e Argument of type 'State' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure to always return the same `State` type in the `reducer` function. If you hover over `reducer`, you see that it currently has following signature:

```
const reducer: (state: State, action: Action) => State | {loading: boolean; error: boolean;}
```

That is, because in `case 'FETCH_ERROR'`,`contractsData` is left out, which is defined as required property in `State`. It can be fixed easily by adding an explicit return type to `reducer` function:

```
const reducer = (state: State, action: Action): State => { ... }
```

and you get the (in this case satisfying!) compile error complaining about the missing property. Finally you can either add an empty `contractsData` array in the `'FETCH_ERROR'` case or define the property as optional in the `State` type.

Solution 1:

```
switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_ERROR':
        return {
            loading: false,
            error: true,
            contractsData: []
        }
}
```

Solution 2:

```
type State = {
    loading: boolean;
    error: boolean;
    contractsData?: ContractObj[];
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=46&ssc=3&pln=28&pc=1#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-kLdchzbTaOx-pRs8MM73nB8+ICyYxQdZ2XPTuK1XubW+QKhSjm72++3O92d2OB4apyPL3O4BOjVATXbX62F4ynW8rpwO6L67ucrakEgMhSjAVg9j+cDXl20wROBu4PPMvB7vwvAcnAAAKTBgIQmy4JhAjCNA8DegoDIvFYyCqAWrTyAAPIREDEWmQYlqmpbzkoiq-CGEZwIchAmDADT-KRRAkE0FBUIGvqKVA2ASCq3jBFq8ZoUh0KsYcABuKaNNKEBwAE0DBKQcCsQA9MZKYekAA)